# How do I dynamically generate a data validation list from table rows

Tags: excel, validation

I'm trying to build a dynamic spreadsheet in order to streamline some combat encounters a role playing game for my friends. On the most basic level, this 'manager' is split into two spreadsheets, a data spreadsheet looking like this:

```
table: enemies (containing general data on enemies)
name    hp  defense
orc     15  10
goblin  5   9
kobold  8   10

table: weapons (containing general data on weapons)
name    dmg pen
spear   4   5
sword   6   4
bow     6   6

table: equipment (since I mix up different weapons on different enemies)
name    weap1   weap2   weap3   weap4   weap5   weap6   weap7   weap8   weap9   weap10
orc     sword   bow
goblin  spear
kobold  sword   bow     spear
```

and a combat spreadsheet that is supposed to use dynamic ranges from those tables and data validation to enable me to cook up encounters on the spot:

```
character           init    hp              defense         weapon  dmg         pen
{enemies[name]}     someVal (vlookup)       (vlookup)       ???     (vlookup)   (vlookup)
```

Now, I can easily pull a list of characters into validation from the enemies table, and I can also vlookup other data from those tables. The problem I have is that I don't know how to pull a 'list' of weapons that character can equip (instead of pulling a bulky list of all weapons) dynamically?

I tried something like this:

```
=OFFSET(Equipments,MATCH(Z19,Equipments[Character],0)-1,1,1,COUNTA(OFFSET(Equipments,MATCH(Z19,Equipments[Character],0)-1,1,1,10)))
```

And the formula evaluates fine, but I get an error if I try to input it into data validation.

Answer (score 0):

List the equipment in this layout:
`name   weap`
`orc    sword`
`orc    bow`
`goblin spear`
`kobold sword`
`kobold bow`
`kobold spear`
And then do this: http://www.contextures.com/xlDataVal02.html